# PL/SQL FIRST LAST EXISTS - (cannot show table contents)

Tags: oracle, plsql, indexof

First, I have read the PL/SQL documentation repeatedly, no help.  Second, I have googled for hours (usually being led here) and still cannot figure this out.

I have created an index table, which seems to have been successful - at least it did not throw any errors...

```
DECLARE
CURSOR cur_emps IS
  SELECT employee_id, last_name, job_id, salary FROM employees ORDER BY employee_id;
  TYPE t_emp_rec IS TABLE OF cur_emps%ROWTYPE
  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  v_emp_rec_tab  t_emp_rec;
BEGIN
  FOR emp_rec IN cur_emps LOOP
    v_emp_rec_tab(emp_rec.employee_id) := emp_rec;
  END LOOP;
```

However, when I try to show what is in my index table.  I fail...

Documentation says do something like this...

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_emps IS
    SELECT employee_id, last_name, job_id, salary FROM employees ORDER BY employee_id;
  TYPE t_emp_rec IS TABLE OF cur_emps%ROWTYPE
  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  v_emp_rec_tab  t_emp_rec;
BEGIN
  FOR emp_rec IN cur_emps LOOP
    v_emp_rec_tab(emp_rec.employee_id) := emp_rec;
  END LOOP;
  FOR i IN v_emp_rec_tab.FIRST..v_emp_rec_tab.LAST LOOP
    IF v_emp_rec_tab.EXISTS(i)
      THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_emp_rec_tab(i));
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

... which gives me this...

ORA-06550: line 13, column 12:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'
ORA-06550: line 13, column 12:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

In place of

```
THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_emp_rec_tab(i));
```

. I have tried 
emp_rec.last_name, v_emp_rec.last_name, cur_emps.last name

... it has been days now trying, can anyone help?

Thanks.
Daniel

Answer (score 4):

You should iterate over an indexed table like this:

```
l_idx := v_emp_rec_tab.first;
while (l_idx is not null) loop
    dbms_output.put_line( v_emp_rec_tab(l_idx).last_name );
    l_idx := v_emp_rec_tab.next(l_idx);
end loop;
```

Otherwise you will get an exception when your table indexes are not consecutive.
See [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:173586000346213111)

Answer (score 2):

v_emp_rec_tab is of rowtype, and it's not possible to call as

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_emp_rec_tab(i));
```

but you can call as :

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_emp_rec_tab(i).last_name);
```

with only one column *or* you might concatenate like :

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_emp_rec_tab(i).last_name||' '||v_emp_rec_tab(i).employee_id);
```

for multiple columns.

Comment: Thank you, Barbaros!  Now it works!  And your explanation was very helpful.